# how to delete a row in a section and hiding the section?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am having an issue where when i have two sections let say section x and section. Section x has one row and also section y. If i delete a row in section y which is the second one, it will delete the row in section x and keeping the row in section y also it leave a space when i hide the section if their is a way to hide the section which wont make a mess please tell me a way here are some picture that might let u understand my question

[image]

[image]

[image]

and here is the code i use to delete a row

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    int path;
    path = indexPath.row;
    [data removeObjectAtIndex:path];
    if([data count] == 0)
    {
        UIBarButtonItem *leftbutton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(editTable)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = leftbutton;
        [leftbutton release];
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setEnabled:FALSE];
        [mainTableView setHidden:TRUE];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setEnabled:TRUE];
        [mainTableView setHidden:FALSE];
    }

    [self saveData];
    [mainTableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove a section when you have deleted all rows belonging to it, call `- (void)deleteSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation` & return one less from `- (NSInteger)numberOfSections`.

You haven't added any code that shows how you are deleting a row from the table (removing it from data isn't sufficient). Try something like-

```
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [data removeObjectAtIndex:path];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: Deleting a row in a section and i have showed some images when i happen to delete a row below the first one

Comment: I have tried your code when let say i `return 4;` it gives me an error about animation i am taking about removing sections

Comment: I have tried it but i keep getting this error `Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted).` there error is marked on `[self.mainTableView endUpdates];`

Comment: I never said copy pasting my code would work. I gave you a sample to delete sections & rows. Try to figure out what is going on & how you can fix any errors that you are seeing.

Comment: You are returning the incorrect value in `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section.`

Comment: The issue is that when their is only one row left in a section the error show other than that its working fine and i am returning the correct amount of sections i have got

Answer (score 0):

Well at the beginning i wasn't able to solve the issue but with the help of @Akshay my first problem was while deleting it always delete the section on top the section i was deleting to solve the issue i just had to update the number of rows in a section using 
`[mainTableView reloadData];` before the return expression